# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, openstreetmap

I am using josm to create a map and for that I am using a local host http://localhost:3000/api and when I query data drom that local host using overpass Api but with python so it is overpy I ise it like this `api = overpy.Overpass(url='http://localhost:3000/api')` and once I start querying data I got his from the server:

```
Started POST "/api" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-31 14:57:23 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api"):

actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
rack-uri_sanitizer (0.0.2) lib/rack/uri_sanitizer.rb:14:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
secure_headers (6.0.0) lib/secure_headers/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

It seems that it is blocked form  the server can anybody help please ?

**Edit :** 
My routes.rb file is as following  and sorry for adding the entire file but I am new in the field :

```
OpenStreetMap::Application.routes.draw do
```

# API

```
get "api/capabilities" => "api#capabilities"

  scope "api/0.6" do
    get "capabilities" => "api#capabilities"
    get "permissions" => "api#permissions"

put "changeset/create" => "changeset#create"
post "changeset/:id/upload" => "changeset#upload", :id => /\d+/
get "changeset/:id/download" => "changeset#download", :as => :changeset_download, :id => /\d+/
post "changeset/:id/expand_bbox" => "changeset#expand_bbox", :id => /\d+/
get "changeset/:id" => "changeset#read", :as => :changeset_read, :id => /\d+/
post "changeset/:id/subscribe" => "changeset#subscribe", :as => :changeset_subscribe, :id => /\d+/
post "changeset/:id/unsubscribe" => "changeset#unsubscribe", :as => :changeset_unsubscribe, :id => /\d+/
put "changeset/:id" => "changeset#update", :id => /\d+/
put "changeset/:id/close" => "changeset#close", :id => /\d+/
get "changesets" => "changeset#query"
post "changeset/:id/comment" => "changeset#comment", :as => :changeset_comment, :id => /\d+/
post "changeset/comment/:id/hide" => "changeset#hide_comment", :as => :changeset_comment_hide, :id => /\d+/
post "changeset/comment/:id/unhide" => "changeset#unhide_comment", :as => :changeset_comment_unhide, :id => /\d+/

put "node/create" => "node#create"
get "node/:id/ways" => "way#ways_for_node", :id => /\d+/
get "node/:id/relations" => "relation#relations_for_node", :id => /\d+/
get "node/:id/history" => "old_node#history", :id => /\d+/
post "node/:id/:version/redact" => "old_node#redact", :version => /\d+/, :id => /\d+/
get "node/:id/:version" => "old_node#version", :id => /\d+/, :version => /\d+/
get "node/:id" => "node#read", :id => /\d+/
put "node/:id" => "node#update", :id => /\d+/
delete "node/:id" => "node#delete", :id => /\d+/
get "nodes" => "node#nodes"

put "way/create" => "way#create"
get "way/:id/history" => "old_way#history", :id => /\d+/
get "way/:id/full" => "way#full", :id => /\d+/
get "way/:id/relations" => "relation#relations_for_way", :id => /\d+/
post "way/:id/:version/redact" => "old_way#redact", :version => /\d+/, :id => /\d+/
get "way/:id/:version" => "old_way#version", :id => /\d+/, :version => /\d+/
get "way/:id" => "way#read", :id => /\d+/
put "way/:id" => "way#update", :id => /\d+/
delete "way/:id" => "way#delete", :id => /\d+/
get "ways" => "way#ways"

put "relation/create" => "relation#create"
get "relation/:id/relations" => "relation#relations_for_relation", :id => /\d+/
get "relation/:id/history" => "old_relation#history", :id => /\d+/
get "relation/:id/full" => "relation#full", :id => /\d+/
post "relation/:id/:version/redact" => "old_relation#redact", :version => /\d+/, :id => /\d+/
get "relation/:id/:version" => "old_relation#version", :id => /\d+/, :version => /\d+/
get "relation/:id" => "relation#read", :id => /\d+/
put "relation/:id" => "relation#update", :id => /\d+/
delete "relation/:id" => "relation#delete", :id => /\d+/
get "relations" => "relation#relations"

get "map" => "api#map"

get "trackpoints" => "api#trackpoints"

get "changes" => "api#changes"

get "search" => "search#search_all", :as => "api_search"
get "ways/search" => "search#search_ways"
get "relations/search" => "search#search_relations"
get "nodes/search" => "search#search_nodes"

get "user/:id" => "user#api_read", :id => /\d+/
get "user/details" => "user#api_details"
get "user/gpx_files" => "user#api_gpx_files"
get "users" => "user#api_users", :as => :api_users

get "user/preferences" => "user_preferences#read"
get "user/preferences/:preference_key" => "user_preferences#read_one"
put "user/preferences" => "user_preferences#update"
put "user/preferences/:preference_key" => "user_preferences#update_one"
delete "user/preferences/:preference_key" => "user_preferences#delete_one"

post "gpx/create" => "traces#api_create"
get "gpx/:id" => "traces#api_read", :id => /\d+/
put "gpx/:id" => "traces#api_update", :id => /\d+/
delete "gpx/:id" => "traces#api_delete", :id => /\d+/
get "gpx/:id/details" => "traces#api_read", :id => /\d+/
get "gpx/:id/data" => "traces#api_data"
# AMF (ActionScript) API
post "amf/read" => "amf#amf_read"
post "amf/write" => "amf#amf_write"
get "swf/trackpoints" => "swf#trackpoints"

# Map notes API
resources :notes, :except => [:new, :edit, :update], :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }, :defaults => { :format => "xml" } do
  collection do
    get "search"
    get "feed", :defaults => { :format => "rss" }
  end

  member do
    post "comment"
    post "close"
    post "reopen"
  end
end

post "notes/addPOIexec" => "notes#create"
post "notes/closePOIexec" => "notes#close"
post "notes/editPOIexec" => "notes#comment"
get "notes/getGPX" => "notes#index", :format => "gpx"
get "notes/getRSSfeed" => "notes#feed", :format => "rss"
```

end

```
# Data browsing
  get "/way/:id" => "browse#way", :id => /\d+/, :as => :way
  get "/way/:id/history" => "browse#way_history", :id => /\d+/
  get "/node/:id" => "browse#node", :id => /\d+/, :as => :node
  get "/node/:id/history" => "browse#node_history", :id => /\d+/
  get "/relation/:id" => "browse#relation", :id => /\d+/, :as => :relation
  get "/relation/:id/history" => "browse#relation_history", :id => /\d+/
  get "/changeset/:id" => "browse#changeset", :as => :changeset, :id => /\d+/
  get "/changeset/:id/comments/feed" => "changeset#comments_feed", :as => :changeset_comments_feed, :id => /\d*/, :defaults => { :format => "rss" }
  get "/note/:id" => "browse#note", :id => /\d+/, :as => "browse_note"
  get "/note/new" => "browse#new_note"
  get "/user/:display_name/history" => "changeset#index"
  get "/user/:display_name/history/feed" => "changeset#feed", :defaults => { :format => :atom }
  get "/user/:display_name/notes" => "notes#mine"
  get "/history/friends" => "changeset#index", :friends => true, :as => "friend_changesets", :defaults => { :format => :html }
  get "/history/nearby" => "changeset#index", :nearby => true, :as => "nearby_changesets", :defaults => { :format => :html }

  get "/browse/way/:id",                :to => redirect(:path => "/way/%{id}")
  get "/browse/way/:id/history",        :to => redirect(:path => "/way/%{id}/history")
  get "/browse/node/:id",               :to => redirect(:path => "/node/%{id}")
  get "/browse/node/:id/history",       :to => redirect(:path => "/node/%{id}/history")
  get "/browse/relation/:id",           :to => redirect(:path => "/relation/%{id}")
  get "/browse/relation/:id/history",   :to => redirect(:path => "/relation/%{id}/history")
  get "/browse/changeset/:id",          :to => redirect(:path => "/changeset/%{id}")
  get "/browse/note/:id",               :to => redirect(:path => "/note/%{id}")
  get "/user/:display_name/edits",      :to => redirect(:path => "/user/%{display_name}/history")
  get "/user/:display_name/edits/feed", :to => redirect(:path => "/user/%{display_name}/history/feed")
  get "/browse/friends",                :to => redirect(:path => "/history/friends")
  get "/browse/nearby",                 :to => redirect(:path => "/history/nearby")
  get "/browse/changesets/feed",        :to => redirect(:path => "/history/feed")
  get "/browse/changesets",             :to => redirect(:path => "/history")
  get "/browse",                        :to => redirect(:path => "/history")

  # web site
  root :to => "site#index", :via => [:get, :post]
  get "/edit" => "site#edit"
  get "/copyright/:copyright_locale" => "site#copyright"
  get "/copyright" => "site#copyright"
  get "/welcome" => "site#welcome"
  get "/fixthemap" => "site#fixthemap"
  get "/help" => "site#help"
  get "/about" => "site#about"
  get "/history" => "changeset#index"
  get "/history/feed" => "changeset#feed", :defaults => { :format => :atom }
  get "/history/comments/feed" => "changeset#comments_feed", :as => :changesets_comments_feed, :defaults => { :format => "rss" }
  get "/export" => "site#export"
  match "/login" => "user#login", :via => [:get, :post]
  match "/logout" => "user#logout", :via => [:get, :post]
  get "/offline" => "site#offline"
  get "/key" => "site#key"
  get "/id" => "site#id"
  get "/query" => "browse#query"
  get "/user/new" => "user#new"
  post "/user/new" => "user#create"
  get "/user/terms" => "user#terms"
  post "/user/save" => "user#save"
  get "/user/:display_name/confirm/resend" => "user#confirm_resend"
  match "/user/:display_name/confirm" => "user#confirm", :via => [:get, :post]
  match "/user/confirm" => "user#confirm", :via => [:get, :post]
  match "/user/confirm-email" => "user#confirm_email", :via => [:get, :post]
  post "/user/go_public" => "user#go_public"
  match "/user/reset-password" => "user#reset_password", :via => [:get, :post]
  match "/user/forgot-password" => "user#lost_password", :via => [:get, :post]
  get "/user/suspended" => "user#suspended"

  get "/index.html", :to => redirect(:path => "/")
  get "/create-account.html", :to => redirect(:path => "/user/new")
  get "/forgot-password.html", :to => redirect(:path => "/user/forgot-password")

  # omniauth
  get "/auth/failure" => "user#auth_failure"
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "user#auth_success", :via => [:get, :post], :as => :auth_success
  match "/auth/:provider" => "user#auth", :via => [:get, :post], :as => :auth

  # permalink
  get "/go/:code" => "site#permalink", :code => /[a-zA-Z0-9_@~]+[=-]*/

  # rich text preview
  post "/preview/:type" => "site#preview", :as => :preview

  # traces
  resources :traces, :except => [:show]
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/tag/:tag/page/:page" => "traces#index", :page => /[1-9][0-9]*/
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/tag/:tag" => "traces#index"
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/page/:page" => "traces#index", :page => /[1-9][0-9]*/
  get "/user/:display_name/traces" => "traces#index"
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/tag/:tag/rss" => "traces#georss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/rss" => "traces#georss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/:id" => "traces#show"
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/:id/picture" => "traces#picture"
  get "/user/:display_name/traces/:id/icon" => "traces#icon"
  get "/traces/tag/:tag/page/:page" => "traces#index", :page => /[1-9][0-9]*/
  get "/traces/tag/:tag" => "traces#index"
  get "/traces/page/:page" => "traces#index", :page => /[1-9][0-9]*/
  get "/traces/tag/:tag/rss" => "traces#georss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/traces/rss" => "traces#georss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/traces/mine/tag/:tag/page/:page" => "traces#mine", :page => /[1-9][0-9]*/
  get "/traces/mine/tag/:tag" => "traces#mine"
  get "/traces/mine/page/:page" => "traces#mine"
  get "/traces/mine" => "traces#mine"
  get "/trace/create", :to => redirect(:path => "/traces/new")
  get "/trace/:id/data" => "traces#data", :id => /\d+/, :as => "trace_data"
  get "/trace/:id/edit", :to => redirect(:path => "/traces/%{id}/edit")
  post "/trace/:id/delete" => "traces#delete", :id => /\d+/

  # diary pages
  match "/diary/new" => "diary_entry#new", :via => [:get, :post]
  get "/diary/friends" => "diary_entry#list", :friends => true, :as => "friend_diaries"
  get "/diary/nearby" => "diary_entry#list", :nearby => true, :as => "nearby_diaries"
  get "/user/:display_name/diary/rss" => "diary_entry#rss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/diary/:language/rss" => "diary_entry#rss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/diary/rss" => "diary_entry#rss", :defaults => { :format => :rss }
  get "/user/:display_name/diary/comments/:page" => "diary_entry#comments", :page => /[1-9][0-9]*/
  get "/user/:display_name/diary/comments/" => "diary_entry#comments"
  get "/user/:display_name/diary" => "diary_entry#list"
  get "/diary/:language" => "diary_entry#list"
  get "/diary" => "diary_entry#list"
  get "/user/:display_name/diary/:id" => "diary_entry#show", :id => /\d+/, :as => :diary_entry
  post "/user/:display_name/diary/:id/newcomment" => "diary_entry#comment", :id => /\d+/
  match "/user/:display_name/diary/:id/edit" => "diary_entry#edit", :via => [:get, :post], :id => /\d+/
  post "/user/:display_name/diary/:id/hide" => "diary_entry#hide", :id => /\d+/, :as => :hide_diary_entry
  post "/user/:display_name/diary/:id/hidecomment/:comment" => "diary_entry#hidecomment", :id => /\d+/, :comment => /\d+/, :as => :hide_diary_comment
  post "/user/:display_name/diary/:id/subscribe" => "diary_entry#subscribe", :as => :diary_entry_subscribe, :id => /\d+/
  post "/user/:display_name/diary/:id/unsubscribe" => "diary_entry#unsubscribe", :as => :diary_entry_unsubscribe, :id => /\d+/

  # user pages
  get "/user/:display_name" => "user#show", :as => "user"
  match "/user/:display_name/make_friend" => "user#make_friend", :via => [:get, :post], :as => "make_friend"
  match "/user/:display_name/remove_friend" => "user#remove_friend", :via => [:get, :post], :as => "remove_friend"
  match "/user/:display_name/account" => "user#account", :via => [:get, :post]
  get "/user/:display_name/set_status" => "user#set_status", :as => :set_status_user
  get "/user/:display_name/delete" => "user#delete", :as => :delete_user

  # user lists
  match "/users" => "user#list", :via => [:get, :post]
  match "/users/:status" => "user#list", :via => [:get, :post]

  # geocoder
  get "/search" => "geocoder#search"
  get "/geocoder/search_latlon" => "geocoder#search_latlon"
  get "/geocoder/search_ca_postcode" => "geocoder#search_ca_postcode"
  get "/geocoder/search_osm_nominatim" => "geocoder#search_osm_nominatim"
  get "/geocoder/search_geonames" => "geocoder#search_geonames"
  get "/geocoder/search_osm_nominatim_reverse" => "geocoder#search_osm_nominatim_reverse"
  get "/geocoder/search_geonames_reverse" => "geocoder#search_geonames_reverse"

  # directions
  get "/directions" => "directions#search"

  # export
  post "/export/finish" => "export#finish"
  get "/export/embed" => "export#embed"

  # messages
  resources :messages, :only => [:create, :show] do
    collection do
      get :inbox
      get :outbox
    end
  end
  get "/user/:display_name/inbox", :to => redirect(:path => "/messages/inbox")
  get "/user/:display_name/outbox", :to => redirect(:path => "/messages/outbox")
  get "/message/new/:display_name" => "messages#new", :as => "new_message"
  get "/message/read/:message_id", :to => redirect(:path => "/messages/%{message_id}")
  post "/message/mark/:message_id" => "messages#mark", :as => "mark_message"
  match "/message/reply/:message_id" => "messages#reply", :via => [:get, :post], :as => "reply_message"
  post "/message/delete/:message_id" => "messages#destroy", :as => "destroy_message"

  # oauth admin pages (i.e: for setting up new clients, etc...)
  scope "/user/:display_name" do
    resources :oauth_clients
  end
  match "/oauth/revoke" => "oauth#revoke", :via => [:get, :post]
  match "/oauth/authorize" => "oauth#authorize", :via => [:get, :post], :as => :authorize
  get "/oauth/token" => "oauth#token", :as => :token
  match "/oauth/request_token" => "oauth#request_token", :via => [:get, :post], :as => :request_token
  match "/oauth/access_token" => "oauth#access_token", :via => [:get, :post], :as => :access_token
  get "/oauth/test_request" => "oauth#test_request", :as => :test_request

  # roles and banning pages
  post "/user/:display_name/role/:role/grant" => "user_roles#grant", :as => "grant_role"
  post "/user/:display_name/role/:role/revoke" => "user_roles#revoke", :as => "revoke_role"
  get "/user/:display_name/blocks" => "user_blocks#blocks_on"
  get "/user/:display_name/blocks_by" => "user_blocks#blocks_by"
  get "/blocks/new/:display_name" => "user_blocks#new", :as => "new_user_block"
  resources :user_blocks
  match "/blocks/:id/revoke" => "user_blocks#revoke", :via => [:get, :post], :as => "revoke_user_block"

  # issues and reports
  resources :issues do
    resources :comments, :controller => :issue_comments
    member do
      post "resolve"
      post "assign"
      post "ignore"
      post "reopen"
    end
  end

  resources :reports

  # redactions
  resources :redactions

  # errors
  match "/403", :to => "errors#forbidden", :via => :all
  match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found", :via => :all
  match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_server_error", :via => :all
end
```

Thanks ,
Jad

Comment: No, its not blocked. The server is telling you that you don't have not defined a [POST] "/api" route. Check your `config/routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

As @max pointed out need to define the route in your config/routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'api', to: 'CONTROLLER_NAME#CONTROLLER_ACTION'
  ...
  ...

end
```

EDIT:

Each line in the routes file you pasted above shows a separate route.

We need to add a route for the method 'POST', the end point 'API', so lets add this line in anywhere between the first and last lines of your route file:

```
post 'api', to: 'CONTROLLER_NAME#CONTROLLER_ACTION'
```

Remembering to switch out the controller name and action for your API controller and API action. Or to put it another way - the controller and action you want to handle the request - maybe:

```
post 'api', to: 'api#get_records'
```

Or keeping the syntax consistent (the below means the same):

```
post "api" => "api#get_records"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry i am new in this field but could you tell me what should I add in my routes.rb file that I just added it to my question.